# how to get current user details with WaterfallDialog?

Tags: python, azure, botframework

I am trying to get current loggedin user details with WaterfallDialog.

```
async def _show_members(
    self, turn_context: TurnContext
):
    member = await TeamsInfo.get_member(turn_context, turn_context.activity.from_property.id)
```

I have tried this but its giving this error

> [on_turn_error] unhandled error: 'WaterfallStepContext' object has no attribute 'activity'

> get_team_id
> channel_data = TeamsChannelData(**turn_context.activity.channel_data)
> AttributeError: 'WaterfallStepContext' object has no attribute 'activity'
> Datetime with no tzinfo will be considered UTC.

Comment: Can you please add more details about the user details that you are trying.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-dialog-manage-complex-conversation-flow?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp) to get the user profile.
You can also check in the [Bot Framework Emulator](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator#readme#readme) that is a cross-platform desktop application that allows users to connect-to and test their local or remote bot, allowing inspection of the conversation history and internal bot state built using the Bot Framework SDK. It can be used to test interactions (text and speech), inspect payloads, generate, save, and load conversation transcripts, and generally promotes fast iteration of bot development.

Below is a list of samples. Check out the whole list https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples

Comment: Thanks for your answer. @Ram-msft I'm using the exact same code given [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/samples/python/15.handling-attachments/bots/attachments_bot.py#L58) but still it doesn't work, I have no clue why. In emulator, it returns "User" but when I try on azure it returns "None"

Comment: Thanks for the details. Raise an issue here for the team to check further on this.https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/issues